# C# , Despite using SecurityProtocol, soap function call fails with error Cannot create secure SSL/TSL channel

Tags: c#, ssl, soap, confluence

We are using Confluence soap service. Despite using the security protocol we are still getting the cannot secure SSL/TLS error.

Can someone help

Code

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

ConfluenceSoapServiceService service = new ConfluenceSoapServiceService();

string Token = service.login("wikiadmin", "wikiadmin");

try

{
  RemotePage page = new RemotePage();

  page.title = "Week of 05/08 - 05/12/2017";

  page.space = "ETS";

  page.content = text;

  page.parentId = 38472651;

  service.storePage(Token, page);  //Getting error here (Cannot secure TLS/SSL Channel)


}
```

Comment: Is ConfluenceSoapServiceService a Windows object? What is your .NET Framework version? I know only TLS 1.0 is supported for .NET 4.0 or older. I don't know what happens if you set it to 1.1 or 1.2.

Comment: Hi Amre, 
The .NET framework is 4.6.2, yes, ConfluenceSoapService service is a windows object. Its a class which gets added when you reference the SOAP service.
We removed TLS1 and tried again with TLS1.1 and TLS1.2, but we are getting the same error.

Comment: Doing a quick google search, it appears that ConfluenceSoapService is actually an Atlassian object, rather than a Microsoft/Windows one. There is no reference to it on MSDN.

I looks like it is actually an interface. I'm assuming you subclassed in ConfluenceSoapServiceService.

I found the JavaDoc for the class here: https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/confluence/4.0/reference/com/atlassian/confluence/rpc/soap/ConfluenceSoapService.html

It says storePage is an abstract method, so error would be coming from your implementation of it. Could we see your code for it?